# how i can get current date without time on MVC view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Curently i am using this code then i submit my data to controller and through controller i add to my database

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.date,  new { @Value=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

Comment: If your property is `DateTime` then it will always have a 'time' component (that's how dates are represented). Do you mean you want the time component to be `00:00` (midnight)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to *show* your time value, then you could do that by specifying the `string` format you want your `DateTime` to show in your `ToString()`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.date,  new { @Value=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") })
```

`dd-MM-yyyy` format will only show day-Month-year elements of the `DateTime`. To show hour-minutes-seconds, use `HH-mm-ss` or `hh-mm-ss`. For more info, check MSDN article on standard and custom date time format.

Comment: Just change the `HH` into `hh` and to display the `AM` and `PM`, you should use `tt`. Check the [MSDN articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)